# Fraction modulo $p$ , modular inverses.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, intuition

My question is about modular inverses and fractions modulo $p$

So I was revising my contest notes, I was trying to think about each topic as if I was explaining it to a child, which is when I realised I did not **actually understand** what fractions modulo $p$ meant:

I understand what something modulo $p$ means, it essentially tells us the remainder when that thing is divided by $p$.

But what does a fraction modulo $p$ even mean?

Like I can say $9 \equiv 2 \mod(7)$ , cause $9 = 7 \cdot 1 + 2$.

But what does it mean to say $\frac{2}{3} \mod (7)$.

I know how to calculate this, it is just $2 \cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 2 \cdot 5 \equiv 10 \equiv 3 \mod(7)$.

But I want to know what it means. Like intuitively, what does this represent? Like what does it mean to say $\frac23 = (0.6666....) \equiv 3 \mod(7)$

If you were to explain it to a layman, how would you, like you'd say $9 \equiv 2 \mod(7)$ because that is the remainder on division by 7. But how would you explain to someone that $\frac23$ is $3$ modulo $7$?

What I think it may mean is that if $\frac sr \equiv a \mod (p)$, then $p$ would need to divide the numerator of $\frac sr - a$.

Thank you!

Comment: Ignore decimals and explaining anything about this to a layman.  A fraction is a solution to a linear equation: if you want to have a meaningful value of $2/3 \bmod 7$ then you are trying to solve $3x \equiv 2 \bmod 7$.  The solution to that is $3$, so $2/3 \equiv 3 \bmod 7$. Consistent with that, the difference $2/3 - 3 = -7/3$ is divisible by 7, in the sense of being a fraction that in reduced form has a numerator divisible by 7.  You can think about this in the sense you give at the end, and there are other ways (localization or $p$-adic numbers), but numerators divisible by $p$ works.

Comment: @KCd , I read your comment, re-read my textbook and notes, thought about it for some time, slept on it for a couple days and now I finally intuitively understand modular inverses; So thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.